# Label text clips at bottom when using CustomFont in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, fonts

I am using Custom Font in iOS application (Xamarin.Forms App).  It is working fine but the text is clipped at the bottom of UILabel.  It clearly cuts letter "g"

**Custom Font**: FuturaStd-Light.ttf

**Actual Image In App:**

[image]

**Edited Image to ensure not height issue:** Added Background color to Label to ensure it is not height issue.

[image]

I read [here](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/fix-vertical-position-issue-of-custom-ios-fonts/) that to adjust ascender and descender property of Font.  But still it doesn't help.  Any help would be really appreciated.

**Note**: It is looking good if we remove custom font.  The issue occurs only for the custom font that i am using.

Comment: May be its not getting enough height, you can check it by applying background color to label, if that's the case then you can increase height of control or decrease font size as per height.

Comment: No.  It is not height issue.  Please check the updated image

Answer (score 1):

you could try to use this:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle paragraphStyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle();
paragraphStyle.MinimumLineHeight = 24 + 1;//24 is your font size
NSMutableDictionary attributes = new NSMutableDictionary();//NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
attributes.SetValueForKey(paragraphStyle,new NSString("NSParagraphStyleAttributeName"));
label.AttributedText = new NSMutableAttributedString(label.Text,attributes);
```